# How should I design a mechanism in C++ to manage relatively generic entities within a simulation?

Tags: c++

I would like to start my question by stating that this is a C++ design question, more then anything, limiting the scope of the discussion to what is accomplishable in that language.

Let us pretend that I am working on a vehicle simulator that is intended to model modern highway systems. As part of this simulation, entities will be interacting with each other to avoid accidents, stop at stop lights and perhaps eventually even model traffic enforcement with radar guns and subsequent exciting high speed chases.

Being a spatial simulation written in C++, it seems like it would be ideal to start with some kind of Vehicle hierarchy, with cars and trucks deriving from some common base class. However, a common problem I have run in to is that such a hierarchy is usually very rigidly defined, and introducing unexpected changes - modeling a boat for instance - tends to introduce unexpected complexity that tends to grow over time into something quite unwieldy.

This simple aproach seems to suffer from a combinatoric explosion of classes. Imagine if I created a MoveOnWater interface and a MoveOnGround interface, and used them to define Car and Boat. Then lets say I add RadarEquipment. Now I have to do something like add the classes RadarBoat and RadarCar. Adding more capabilities using this approach and the whole thing rapidly becomes quite unreasonable.

One approach I have been investigating to address this inflexibility issue is to do away with the inheritance hierarchy all together. Instead of trying to come up with a type safe way to define everything that could ever be in this simulation, I defined one class - I will call it 'Entity' - and the capabilities that make up an entity - can it drive, can it fly, can it use radar - are all created as interfaces and added to a kind of capability list that the Entity class contains. At runtime, the proper capabilities are created and attached to the entity and functions that want to use these interfaced must first query the entity object and check for there existence. This approach seems to be the most obvious alternative, and is working well for the time being. I, however, worry about the maintenance issues that this approach will have. Effectively any arbitrary thing can be added, and there is no single location in which all possible capabilities are defined. Its not a problem currently, when the total number of things is quite small, but I worry that it might be a problem when someone else starts trying to use and modify the code.

As one potential alternative, I pondered using the template system to achieve type safe while keeping the same kind of flexibility. I imagine I could create entities that inherited whatever combination of interfaces I wanted. Using these objects would entail creating a template class or function that used any combination of the interfaces. One example might be the simple move on road using just the MoveOnRoad interface, whereas more complex logic, like a "high speed freeway chase", could use methods from both MoveOnRoad and Radar interfaces.

Of course making this approach usable mandates the use of boost concept check just to make debugging feasible. Also, this approach has the unfortunate side effect of making "optional" interfaces all but impossible. It is not simple to write a function that can have logic to do one thing if the entity has a RadarEquipment interface, and do something else if it doesn't. In this regard, type safety is somewhat of a curse. I think some trickery with boost any may be able to pull it off, but I haven't figured out how to make that work and it seems like way to much complexity for what I am trying to achieve.

Thus, we are left with the dynamic "list of capabilities" and achieving the goal of having decision logic that drives behavior based on what the entity is capable of becomes trivial.

Now, with that background in mind, I am open to any design gurus telling me where I err'd in my reasoning. I am eager to learn of a design pattern or idiom that is commonly used to address this issue, and the sort of tradeoffs I will have to make.

I also want to mention that I have been contemplating perhaps an even more random design. Even though I my gut tells me that this should be designed as a high performance C++ simulation, a part of me wants to do away with the Entity class and object-orientated foo all together and uses a relational model to define all of these entity states. My initial thought is to treat entities as an in memory database and use procedural query logic to read  and write the various state information, with the necessary behavior logic that drives these queries written in C++. I am somewhat concerned about performance, although it would not surprise me if that was a non-issue. I am perhaps more concerned about what maintenance issues and additional complexity this would introduce, as opposed to the relatively simple list-of-capabilities approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate what varies and Prefer object composition to inheritance, are the two OOAD principles at work here.

Check out the Bridge Design pattern. I visualize Vehicle abstraction as one thing that varies, and the other aspect that varies is the "Medium". Boat/Bus/Car are all Vehicle abstractions, while Water/Road/Rail are all Mediums.

I believe that in such a mechanism, there may be no need to maintain any capability. For example, if a Bus cannot move on Water, such a behavior can be modelled by a NOP behavior in the Vehicle Abstraction.

> Use the Bridge pattern when
>
> you want to avoid a permanent binding
>   between an abstraction and its
>   implementation. This might be the
>   case, for example, when the
>   implementation must be selected or
>   switched at run-time.
>
> both the abstractions and their
>   implementations should be extensible
>   by subclassing. In this case, the
>   Bridge pattern lets you combine the
>   different abstractions and
>   implementations and extend them
>   independently.
>
> changes in the implementation of an
>   abstraction should have no impact on
>   clients; that is, their code should
>   not have to be recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, with that background in mind, I am open to any design gurus telling me where I err'd in my reasoning.

You may be erring in using C++ to define a system for which you as yet have no need/no requirements:

> This approach seems to be the most
>   obvious alternative, and is working
>   well for the time being. I, however,
>   worry about the maintenance issues
>   that this approach will have.
>   Effectively any arbitrary thing can be
>   added, and there is no single location
>   in which all possible capabilities are
>   defined. Its not a problem currently,
>   when the total number of things is
>   quite small, but I worry that it might
>   be a problem when someone else starts
>   trying to use and modify the code.

Maybe you should be considering principles like [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it) as opposed to [BDUF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Design_Up_Front).

Some of my personal favourites are from [Systemantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemantics):

"15. A complex system that works is invariably found to have evolved from a simple system that works"

"16. A complex system designed from scratch never works and cannot be patched up to make it work. You have to start over, beginning with a working simple system."

You're also worring about performance, when you have no defined performance requirements, and no problems with performance:

> I am somewhat concerned about
>   performance, although it would not
>   surprise me if that was a non-issue.

Also, I hope you know about [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), which might be useful for implementing anything-to-anything interactions (it's described in some detail in *More Effective C++* by Scott Meyers).